# YQL Console: No definition found for Table htmlstring

Tags: javascript, yql, yahoo-api

I don't know if Yahoo changed something during the night, but what worked yesterday doesn't today...

So if you try [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=env%20%22store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys%22%3B%20select%20*%20from%20htmlstring%20where%20url%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%22), it will work and return the expected HTML from Google homepage.

If you try [this](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=use%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Fyql%2Fyql-tables%2Fmaster%2Fdata%2Fhtmlstring.xml%22%20as%20htmlstring%3B%20select%20*%20from%20htmlstring%20where%20url%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%22#), it will also work as expected.

Now if I try to use JavaScript to call the REST queries provided by YQL Console to do my call, I receive the below message:

```
{"error": {
  "description": "No definition found for Table htmlstring",
  "diagnostics": {"url": {
    "content": "http://www.datatables.org/data/htmlstring.xml",
    "execution-stop-time": "1",
    "http-status-message": "Bad Request",
    "execution-time": "1",
    "http-status-code": "400",
    "execution-start-time": "0"
  }},
  "lang": "en-US"
}}
```

Here is the JavaScript I use:

```
var createCORSRequest=function(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // XDomainRequest for IE.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

// Make an actual CORS request.
var makeCorsRequest=function(url) {
  var deferred=jQuery.Deferred();
  var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
  if (!xhr) {
    deferred.fail('CORS not supported');
    return;
  }
  // Response handlers.
  xhr.onload = function() {
    deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
  };
  xhr.onerror = function() {
    deferred.fail('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
  };
  xhr.send();
  return deferred;
}

var resturl = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=env%20%22store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys%22%3B%20select%20*%20from%20htmlstring%20where%20url%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=";
makeCorsRequest(resturl).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

Side note: on the YQL Console it works almost all the time, but I received some fails. So I'm wondering if there is an outage of YQL ?

Comment: Same here, it works every now and then.. Gives me HTTP Status 400, Bad request most of the time. YQL has been working wonderfully all year and this is the first time Iäm having problems with it. Hopefully it'll get resolved soon.

Comment: Seems like they've ended support for htmlstring

Comment: Have you got an answer for your question? I'm also getting this error. @AymKdn

Comment: No answer found.... I think the service is slowly dieing, so I finished using my own server

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's related but i think that they have been hacked, look this, another header in their servers. Weird link: [Yahoo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vEZ2.png)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it's related, but the YQL console is failing to return results for RSS queries.
For example, this fails:

```
select * from rss where url="http://razamazazzle.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default"
```